# CakePHP 3.4 Disable the wrapping DIV on Input Field

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I disable the wapping DIV for an element in CakePHP 3.4?

Now it looks like:

```
<div class="input text">
  <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search" id="query">
</div>
```

But it should look like

```
<input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search" id="query">
```

The PHP Code:

```
<?= $this->Form->control("query", array(
    "label" => false,
    "placeholder"=>__("Search"))); 
?>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: i think you are missing one more bracket `<?= $this->Form->control("query", array("label" => false, "placeholder"=>__("Search"))); ?>`

Comment: Yes you are right. Fixed it.

Comment: Did it fix your problem?

Comment: No - the wrapper class is still "input text" ... it should be blank or "field" .... so it won't conflict with the css classes of semantic-ui

Comment: try `<?= $this->Form->control("query", array("label" => false, "div"=>false, "placeholder"=>__("Search"))); ?>`

Comment: Fixed it like described in the docs https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use CakePHP Form `Template` to customize the auto generated `HTML` tags.

**Example :** In `add.ctp`

```
$custom_template = [
    'button' => '<button{{attrs}}>{{text}}</button>',
    'checkbox' => '<input type="checkbox" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}"{{attrs}}>',
    'checkboxFormGroup' => '{{label}}',
    'checkboxWrapper' => '<div class="checkbox">{{label}}</div>',
    'dateWidget' => '{{year}}{{month}}{{day}}{{hour}}{{minute}}{{second}}{{meridian}}',
    'error' => '<div class="error-message">{{content}}</div>',
    'errorList' => '<ul>{{content}}</ul>',
    'errorItem' => '<li>{{text}}</li>',
    'file' => '<input type="file" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>',
    'fieldset' => '<fieldset{{attrs}}>{{content}}</fieldset>',
    'formStart' => '<form{{attrs}}><div class="box-body">',
    'formEnd' => '</div></form>',
    'formGroup' => '{{label}}{{input}}',
    'hiddenBlock' => '<div style="display:none;">{{content}}</div>',
    'input' => '<input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}/>',
    'inputSubmit' => '<input type="{{type}}"{{attrs}}/>',
    'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group {{type}}{{required}}"><div class="form-line">{{content}}</div></div>',
    'inputContainerError' => '<div class="input {{type}}{{required}} error">{{content}}{{error}}</div>',
    'label' => '<label{{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>',
    'nestingLabel' => '{{hidden}}<label{{attrs}}>{{input}}{{text}}</label>',
    'legend' => '<legend>{{text}}</legend>',
    'multicheckboxTitle' => '<legend>{{text}}</legend>',
    'multicheckboxWrapper' => '<fieldset{{attrs}}>{{content}}</fieldset>',
    'option' => '<option value="{{value}}"{{attrs}}>{{text}}</option>',
    'optgroup' => '<optgroup label="{{label}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</optgroup>',
    'select' => '<select class="form-control" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select>',
    'selectMultiple' => '<select name="{{name}}[]" multiple="multiple"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select>',
    'radio' => '<input type="radio" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}"{{attrs}}>',
    'radioWrapper' => '{{label}}',
    'textarea' => '<textarea name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{value}}</textarea>',
    'submitContainer' => '<div class="submit">{{content}}</div>',
];
$this->Form->templates($custom_template);

echo $this->Form->input('name',['type'=>'text']);
```

**Above Template will generate below HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group text">
  <div class="form-line">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input name="name" class="form-control" id="name" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

> Here is the documentation for [Customizing the Form Templates](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 

echo $this->Form->control('query', array(
    'div' => false,
    'label' => false,
    'placeholder' => __('Search'))); 
?>
```